# bad magic number in superblock in disk cloned with ddrescue

Tags: data-recovery, clone, ddrescue

I am in deep water here and would appreciate some help. I feel I must be missing something basic.

I have a failing 2TB external HDD, with an NTFS file system. The drive is about half-full of data. I attempted to clone this using ddrescue to a brand new 2tb external SSD with an ext4 file system. (my research suggested it would be fine to use ddrescue with two different file system types—perhaps this was the problem?)

I ran ddrescue using the following command:

`sudo ddrescue --force -n /dev/sdb /dev/sda rescue.map`

The device names are correct. It took 24 hours and reported 99.99% of the disk rescued (good!), 450 read errors, and a handful of bad blocks.

I then ran a second pass using this command:

`sudo ddrescue --force -d -r3 -n /dev/sdb /dev/sda rescue.map`

Much the same number of read errors reported. But, I figured, most of the data was going to be OK.

However, when I ran

`fsck -f /dev/sda`

it told me that there was a bad magic number in the superblock, that the superblock must be corrupt, and that I should try with e2fsck with a different superblock. I tried the suggestions. Both returned the same error.

I can mount and open the drive in a file browser, but all it seems to have on it is a30GB (!) lost and found folder.

So I am really puzzled. Where is the 99.99% of rescued data? Why is the brand new disk corrupt? Have I missed something really, really simple or basic?

If needs be, I am happy to start over again with reformatting the new drive and running ddrescue again, but I would like to get it right this time.

Comment: It is not a good idea to clone a bad disk. In particular, I would repair the NTFS file system with ntfsfix, then move the undamaged files to the new disk, and then try to recover the damaged ones with testdisk. Previously reformatting the new disk.

Comment: Thanks. I did wonder if cloning the disk was a bad idea. I am worried that trying to repair the file system will further damage the disk, but perhaps it is the best move.